# GNU make - How to concatenate to variable depending on shell command result (GCC version)?

Tags: linux, shell, make, gcc, gnu-make

I want to add another option to the CFLAGS make variable, depending on the result of a shell command that i want to execute outside of a recipe in my "configuration" section of the makefile. This is what i have come up with:

```
GCC_VERSION := $(shell gcc -dumpversion); \
if [[ ${GCC_VERSION} > 5.0 ]] ; then \
    CFLAGS += -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L; \
fi
```

At first i execute the command with the shell make function as you see above. If i execute the above it doesn't add this define flag. I intentionally do this on linux with GCC Version 5.4.0. I believe this is wrong because then i have to create a new shell to execute the conditional statement. In that new shell though the GCC_VERSION variable will not exist. I could be wrong though.

If i do like this then (all in one shell):

```
$(shell GCC_VERSION=$(gcc -dumpversion); \
if [[ ${GCC_VERSION} > 5.0 ]] ; then \
    CFLAGS += -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L; \
fi)
```

i get error:

```
*** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Yeah, very confusing.

If someone could help i would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The error means that you have an out-of-place shell command. That's because your `if` follows the `bash` syntax, not the `make` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many solutions, including this one. In your Makefile use

```
VERSION5 := $(shell \
 GCC_VERSION=$$(gcc -dumpversion); \
 [[ $$GCC_VERSION > 5.0 ]]; \
 echo $$? )

ifeq (${VERSION5}, 0)
  CFLAGS += -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L
endif
```

Note in particular, that you need to use `$$` for every `$` in your shell script. This shell echos 0 if the string comparision with `5.0` is true, else 1, and this is saved in make variable `VERSION5`.

Then the `ifeq` test in the Makefile compares the variable with 0 and if it matches edits the `CFLAGS` variable.

Comment: You might need to use `[...]` instead of `[[...]]` if the shell that gmake runs is old or strictly POSIX conforming.